# Trigger 'reloadGrid' affects the frozen column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, contextmenu, free-jqgrid, frozen-columns

I am using free-jqgrid, v4.15.2

I have a grid with some frozen column and contextMenu feature. It works well. contextMenu work in all frozen columns and normal columns.

The problem occured when I set new data for grid and call trigger **reloadGrid** to apply new data. contextMenu is still work in normals column, but on in frozen columns.

Does **reloadGrid** affect the contextMenu feature on the frozen column?

Note: I have a plunk in comment. Onload, If you right click on the first 2 columns and the remaining columns, you will see 1 menucontext with 3 options. And then, click **Refresh**, grid will reload with new data, but on right-click on first 2 columns, menu not occur. That's exactly my problem. >_< !!!

Comment: My plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/BqsRMDjkB4MpxBPE9ugP?p=preview